# Eclipse Tomcat doesn't see files in deployment directory

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, http-status-code-404

I have Eclipse Web Project using Java and Tomcat 7.0.

I have it associated to a Tomcat 7.0 server instance.

When I start the Server in Eclipse, it moves all the files to the deployment under .metadata/.... etc.

When I put a file in that path under ROOT, it serves up and displays.  But all the files that were deployed by server start/synchronization under their directory context /xxxx/file.html, are showing 404 errors.  I can see them in the directory.  Move it to ROOT, and it serves up on the page.

It's only this one project.  I copied the entire project out, and then created a NEW project based on those files, and I get the same behavior.

Any advice on where to look for logs (tomcat log shows just a 404 on the file, nothing in Console) or what might be wrong?

Comment: In eclipse, a "server" can be defined in two ways though I can't remember exactly which is which but if you double click the server to see its configuration page, then select deployments tab at bottom, theres a radio option that shows: 1. Use Workspace metadata 2. Use JBoss deploy folder (I'm working with Jboss so yours likely says Tomcat) 3. Use custom deploy folder.  I'm guessing it's using the workspace meta data on your server instance and possibly thats whats causing the issue?

Comment: It appears the Server context.xml got nuked when I was doing a drop and recreate, and that failed to load my MYSQL class as a connection pool.  This was preventing the instance from fully standing up and reverting to Apache on the ROOT dir.  Once it was entered back in context.xml, it all came back up.

Comment: Glad you got it working Robert!